# bcryptjs and mysql issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

I want to save user in database and create hash of his password and save it instead password
but all my attempts to do that cause RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

here is User code

```
import db from "./db";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

class User {
    constructor(name, surname, login, pass) {
        var user = new User();
        user.name = name;
        user.surname = surname;
        user.login = login;
        user.pass =pass;
    }

    save(cb){
        let sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, surname, login, hash) VALUE ?";
        let values = [[this.name, this.surname, this.login, this.hash]];
        this.hashPass((result)=>{
            db.query(sql, [values], cb);
        });
    };

    hashPass(pass, cb){
        bcrypt.genSalt(8,(err, salt) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            bcrypt.hash(pass, salt, (result)=>{
                cb(result);
            });
        });
    }

    varification(login, password, cb) {
        bcrypt.compare(pass, hash, (err, result) => {
            cb(result);
        });
    }
}

export default User;
```

here is where a try to save user

```
router.post('/regist', (req, res)=> {
    let entryData = req.body;

    let newUser = new User(entryData.name, entryData.surname, entryData.login, entryData.password);

    newUser.save((err, result)=> {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 1):

`RangeError` happens because `User` constructor is recursively invoked inside `User` constructor. Try to remove the recursive call:

```
constructor(name, surname, login, pass) {
    user.name = name;
    user.surname = surname;
    user.login = login;
    user.pass =pass;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Sure I should have noticed it.